# npm urllib ResponseTimeoutError - how to increase timeout?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, urllib

I am trying to use urllib to go to many different URLs to get some HTML and parse it. I have a loop that should go through about 5000 iterations with urllib:

```
urllib.request('a url here', options=[timeout=50000]).then(function (result) {
                // data is Buffer instance
                var $ = cheerio.load(result.data);
                $('dt').each(function () {
                    var news_html = cheerio.load($(this).html());
                    if (news_html('span.timestamp').html() != null) {
                        var date = news_html('span.timestamp').html();
                        var description = news_html('.story_title').html();
                        var link = news_html('a').attr('href');
                        var post = {description: description, date: date, link: link};
                        pool.query('INSERT INTO db SET ?', post, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
```

After about 100 iterations, I get this error:

```
{ ResponseTimeoutError: Response timeout for 5000ms, GET http://www.streetinsider.com/stock_lookup_news.php?q=CREG&type=major_news -1 (connected: true, keepalive socket: false)
headers: {}
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/max/projects/stock-news-angular/node_modules/urllib/lib/urllib.js:715:15)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
  name: 'ResponseTimeoutError',
  requestId: 595,
  data: undefined,
  path: '/stock_lookup_news.php?q=CREG&type=major_news',
  status: -1,
  headers: {},
  res: 
   { status: -1,
     statusCode: -1,
     headers: {},
     size: 0,
     aborted: false,
     rt: 10030,
     keepAliveSocket: false,
     data: undefined,
     requestUrls: [ 'http://www.streetinsider.com/stock_lookup_news.php?q=CREG&type=major_news' ],
     timing: null,
     remoteAddress: '162.242.133.50',
     remotePort: 80 } }
```

How can I go about increasing the timeout so that I can finish the loop and insert all the required data into my MySQL db? I think I am not correctly understanding how to set the timeout, as npm's urllib does have an option to set that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding `timeout` option args for [request()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib#method-httprequesturl-options-callback) function can solve your problem.

In API doc:

> timeout Number | Array - Request timeout in milliseconds for connecting phase and response receiving phase. Defaults to exports.TIMEOUT, both are 5s. You can use timeout: 5000 to tell urllib use same timeout on two phase or set them seperately such as timeout: [3000, 5000], which will set connecting timeout to 3s and response 5s.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not exactly sure how I'm supposed to set it. The method seems to take three arguments: `http.request(url[, options][, callback])` but I'm not too familiar with JS syntax and wasn't sure how to add the timeout. I tried `urllib.request({url: [url], options: [timeout=50000]})`, which didn't work either.

Comment: @needhelpwithR try like this:

`http.request('http://example.com', {
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    'a': 'hello',
    'b': 'world'
  },
  timeout: 10000 // 10s
});`

Comment: It does not work when I add that. I get an ECONNRESET error: `Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:564:26)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  name: 'ResponseError',`

Comment: Didn't modifying `urllib.request('a url here', options=[timeout=50000])` to `urllib.request('a url here', { timeout: 50000 })` work? I think what you have to do is modifying the 1st line of your code on the original post.

Comment: It increased the timeout, but I get another error (the one above).

Comment: If timeout issue was resolved, this question is done. Please ask a new question about the next error with detailed information.